# How to call keystrokes CTRL+V in Node js ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nwjs

How to invoke a simulated key CTRL+V in the nodejs ?
I use the nwjs,in the applications I use Iframe, in which I find the element input. 
For this input, I want to run the event CTRL+V (Paste).
Since I already have a copied value, I want to run a paste event for this input.

I wanted to try through document.execCommand('paste'). But inside input it is impossible to execute event document.execCommand('paste').

How can I implement this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It's a major security issue.

Comment: Simulating keystrokes in nodejs is very different from similating them in a nw.js iframe (which is more akin to working in a browser). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: For example, in the iframe there is html input tag.
I just want to write a value in this Input tag and click on the Ok button.

But simple $('#input').val('test') not poluchaetsya, it changes only visually, when you press the button OK, the value on the input leaves the default value.